# Improving Jboss 4.2 very slow startup

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, jboss-4.2.x

Jboss takes hell lot of time for startup. Same Jboss settings and app takes no time to start in my collegaue system.

```
E:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\bin>run -c ags7.3Ingrn
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: E:\jboss-4.2.2.GA

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_07\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n  -Dprogram.name=run.bat -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

  CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_07\lib\tools.jar;E:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\bin\run.jar

===============================================================================

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: E:\jboss-4.2.2.GA
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Home URL: file:/E:/jboss-4.2.2.GA/
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Server Name: ags7.3Ingrn
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: E:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\ags7.3Ingrn
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/E:/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/ags7.3Ingrn/
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: E:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\ags7.3Ingrn\log
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: E:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\ags7.3Ingrn\tmp
14:01:31,531 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
14:01:32,765 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.5.0_07,Sun Microsystems Inc.
14:01:32,765 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.5.0_07-b03,Sun Microsystems Inc.
14:01:32,765 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows XP 5.1,x86
14:01:35,156 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
14:01:46,093 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
14:01:46,109 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml.
```

It simply stops on "Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml" and get started in 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

This is very common, but in most cases JBoss **is** starting up successfully. What's actually happening is the logging appender for console output is either missing or the level of logging has been changed so that you're not seeing INFO messages any more.

The easiest test for this is to back up your existing jboss-log4j.xml file, then copy the original (from your JBoss download) over the top, so you're going back to default settings. Then restart JBoss and all should be well.